# Computing Taylor polynomial of a infinitely differentiable function that is a composite of non-differentiable functions

Tags: calculus

I'm a little stuck with the problem of obtaining the taylor polynomial to a certain degree of a function $f(x) = g(h(x))$ around a point $a$. I do know that $f$ is infinitely differentiable at $a$ but $g$ is not differentiable at $h(a)$.

Specifically, I'm looking at f(x) = $\sqrt{h(x)}$ with $h(a) = 0$. 
I do have the Taylor polynomial of $g$ (to a an arbitrary degree) around $a$. Is there any way of obtaining the Taylor polynomial of $f$ from this?

Context: I am using a library that computes Taylor polynomials by composing Taylor polynomials of simple functions. In my example this of course doesn't work.

Comment: In general, it won't have a Taylor series.  Say $h(x)=x^2,\ a = 0$  Then $f(x)=|x|$ which doesn't have a Taylor series at $x=0.$

Comment: You're right, but I do explicitly know that $f(x)$ has a Taylor series. I just don't know how to obtain it.

Comment: Then tell us what $h$ is in your specific case, please.

Comment: If you know that $f^2(x)=h(x)$ and you know the Taylor series for $h=\sum b_n x^n$ and you assume $f(x)$ is given by a Taylor series $f(x)=\sum a_n x^n$, you can solve iteratively for the $a_n$ in terms of the $b_n$.  Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: This is exactly what I am looking for. I wanted to edit the question to write down the actual $h(x)$, but it is a bit complicated (It is the square root of the predictive covariance of a Gaussian Process, see e.g. [1], last equation ). Could you elaborate on the method to obtain the Taylor polynomial?

[1]: https://towardsdatascience.com/quick-start-to-gaussian-process-regression-36d838810319

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know that $f^2(x)=h(x)$ and you know the Taylor series for $h=\sum_{n=0}^\infty b_n x^2$ and you assume that $f(x)$ is given by a Taylor series $f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n x^2,$ you can solve iteratively for the $a_n$ in terms of the $b_n$ by comparing coefficients.

We have $$(a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2+\cdots)^2=b_0+b_1x+b_2x^2+\cdots$$ so
$$\begin{align}
a_0^2&=b_0\\
2a_0a_1&=b_1\\
2a_0a_2+a_1^2&=b_2\\
&\vdots
\end{align}$$
Solve the first equation for $a_0$ and substitute the result in the second equation to get $a_1$ and so on.

In general, we have $$b_n=\sum_{k=0}^n a_na_{n-k}=2a_0a_n+\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}a_ka_{n-k}$$ which you can easily solve to get an explicit formula for $a_n$ in terms of $b_n$ and the previously-computed $a_k$.

I hope this is what you need.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!

Comment: Glad I could help.